# Unit testing with the config app file in Laravel

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5

My model method relies on the `config()` global, here;

```
public function getGroup()
{
    if(config('app.pages.'.$this->group.'.0')) {
        return $this->group;
    }
    return "city";
}
```

I am trying to test this method in my unit test class, here;

```
public function testGetGroupReturnsCityAsDefault()
{
    $response = new Response();
    $response->group = "town";
    $test = $response->getGroup();
    dd($test);
}
```

The error I get is;

```
Error: Call to a member function make() on null
/home/vagrant/sites/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:62
/home/vagrant/sites/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:163
```

I know this is related to the config() global. But not sure how to set it in my test. I tried

```
public function setUp()
{
config(['app.pages' => [
    'city' => [........
```

But got the same error. How can I set this up?

Answer (score 18):

I'm not sure if you have solved this yet but I just had a similar issue.

There were two things I had to do to get it to work:

1. Make sure you are calling the setUp parent method like so:

```php
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    // other stuff
}
```

2. Make sure your test class is extending the Laravel `TestCase` rather than the `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`

**Brief explanation**: Basically the error you are getting is because the `ContainerInstance` of Laravel is null since you are going through PHPUnit and as such it was never created. If you do the above steps you'll ensure that Laravel will first instantiate a container instance.

**P.S.** If you are going to end up ultimately referencing `env` variables, you should look into the `phpunit.xml`section for environment variables.

Comment: Thank you for the solve, Forgot to use the parent::setUp() method.

Comment: It's worth noting that in later versions of laravel, this example will not work as it needs to be compatible with the parent method and use the `void` return type like so:  `public function setUp(): void`

Comment: For me, it was #2! Thanks so much!

Answer (score -3):

**PHP Unit Test Implement in Laravel**

1) install php unit in your system

```
composer global require phpunit/phpunit *

- Add this configuration in below path in  D:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.5\php.ini

[xdebug]
        zend_extension="d:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.3.5/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.7.2-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll"
        xdebug.remote_enable = on
        xdebug.profiler_enable = off
        xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = Off
        xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
        xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="d:/wamp64/tmp"
        xdebug.show_local_vars=0
        xdebug.remote_autostart=On
```

2) check in CMD - phpunit
    - Create .env.testing and create new test database
    - Create Faker for dummy data
    - write test case logic

3)phpunit file_path --filter FunctionName

4)phpunit --coverage-html reports/

**phpunit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
      <testsuite name="APIs">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/APIs</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./report"
            lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80" />
    </logging>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

**ExampleTest.php**

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```