# Imposible to use Factory in PHPUnit / Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to make functional tests with PHPUnit / Integrated.

So, what I need is to generate a fake object, and fill all fields in my form.

Thing is when I try to generate a Person with Faker, I get this error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function make() on null in /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 62
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:47
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:100
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:149
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:440
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:747
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:747
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:724
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php:612
PHP  10. UserRegisterTest->setUp() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:764
PHP  11. factory() /home/vagrant/RH/tests/selenium/UserRegisterTest.php:14
PHP  12. app() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:371

Fatal error: Call to a member function make() on null in /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 62

Call Stack:
    0.0007     229664   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:0
    0.3939    2354648   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:47
    0.3940    2355272   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:100
    4.4996    6652288   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:149
    4.5334    6871768   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:440
    4.5514    6887848   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:747
    4.5555    6892152   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:747
    4.5556    6893792   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:724
    4.6299    6963232   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php:612
    4.6300    6981248  10. UserRegisterTest->setUp() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:764
    4.6300    6981448  11. factory() /home/vagrant/RH/tests/selenium/UserRegisterTest.php:14
    4.6300    6981568  12. app() /home/vagrant/RH/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:371
```

UserRegisterTest.php

```
/**
 *
 * @test
 * Register a new user with partial information
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function capture_new_user_with_partial_information()
{
    $this->person = factory(Person::class)->create(); // Gives me an error 
}
```

ModelFactory.php

```
$factory->define(RH\Person::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
return [
    'nombre' => $faker->firstName,
    'apellido_paterno' => $faker->lastName,
    'apellido_materno' => $faker->lastName,
    // There is more fields

];
});
```

I understand I could do it in static way, but I feel it is better to test with random data.

Comment: uyyy, Paste failing! Now, I updated the question

Comment: Try this: `$user = factory(Person::class)->create();` Any error?

Comment: And the `factory(RH\Person::class)->create()` ? Or `factory(\RH\Person::class)->create()` ?

Comment: see this question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041613/unit-testing-with-the-config-app-file-in-laravel/35114700#35114700

Comment: tested, but still the same error

Comment: @tam I already tried SetUp method, but it is not working

Comment: I extend Selenium, forgot about that, I use Integrated package

Comment: ok it is hard for me to tell without seeing your code but the error you are getting is because you are never instantiating a laravel application instance. this happens in the TestCase.php provided with laravel. if you want to use integrated, i believe you need to have your test extend TestCase, and have TestCase extend the integrated class

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the error, but I don't really know how to fix... Can you give me any clue? I can show you any piece of code you need

Comment: I tried to put         $app = $this->createApplication();
 in setUp Method, but it seems createApplication does not exist :(

Comment: I m eating but in 1 hour it should be excellent bcs I didn t find a solution :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105941/discussion-between-juliatzin-del-toro-and-tam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error `Call to a member function make() on null` because you never instantiated an instance of the Laravel application container. When your entry point is through tests, you need to make sure to instantiate it if you are going to be depending on it.

Thus, laravel provides a `TestCase.php` which contains a method `createApplication()` which accomplishes this for you.

You need to have your test extend this class so that the `parent::setUp()` method will instantiate an application instance.

In your case, you are trying to use Selenium with the Integrated package. What you can do is have your test class extend TestCase and change the beginning of your `TestCase.php` to:

```
<?php

use Laracasts\Integrated\Extensions\Selenium;

class TestCase extends Selenium
{
     // leave whatever else was here
}
```

This should solve your issue.

If you have multiple test suites for which you want to use different packages or something like that, then it may be a good idea to create multiple TestCase classes, or something like that, you can work on that part... ;p (just add the new TestCase to your composer.json)

Comment: Solution were to copy   TestCase to SeleniumTestCase as you said!